# Open a web page and send data to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an application that does the below.

1. There will be a webpage with 2 text boxes, and a submit button.
2. When the user enters details and submits, An API gateway is triggered that will save the data to a database. (I am able to do it till here).
3. Now once the values are stored, I'm getting back a response code from my API gateway to my webpage, is there a way that I can trigger another lambda function? like `if(success)` in HTML send response to a lambda function

else in simple words, create a HTML page in lambda, once the user submits the data, get the response in same lambda function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible by using [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property), but you need to provide AWS Credentials. If you using Lambda behind API Gateway for save the data - the best option is - after successfully save, make [call to STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRole-property) for temporary security credentials (that will allow to invoke Lambda) and return them together with result.

By doing that - you can invoke lambda in browser using that returned temporary security credentials and pass the returned result.

Comment: Thanks Michal for quick response. I am really sorry to say this, I didn't quite get the concept :(

Comment: Hold on, I'll prepare picture for you... ;D